# MySQL - Combining 2 Counts unless values are present in both

Tags: mysql, sql, linqpad

I have 2 columns in 1 table that I need to combine the COUNT() of each together. However, if both columns have a value, then that row needs to only be counted once.

Here's what I've tried but doesn't work:

```
SELECT SUM( IF (table1.col1 IS NOT NULL OR table1.col2 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) )
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table1.id
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.personid
WHERE table3.otherid = 1 
    AND table1.col1 > '2000-01-01';*


Sample Data:
Table 1
Col1......Col2
04/17/2013........04/17/2013
null..........04/17/2013
03/26/2013.......02/17/2013
03/25/2013.........null
null.........null
02/22/2013...........02/21/2013
```

Result should be = 5. Because 5 records with at least 1 date in either column, but the records with dates in both columns are only counted once

Comment: Sample data and entire tested query edited :)

Comment: You never mentioned table2 or table3 in your original question !

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table1.id
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table3.id = table2.personid
WHERE table3.otherid = 1 
    AND (table1.col1 > '2000-01-01' OR table1.col2 > '2000-01-01');
```